# Rails: unknown attribute error for derived class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named `PaypalPayment`:

```
class PaypalPayment < PaymentMethod
  belongs_to :order
  def provider_class
    PaypalPayment
  end

  def process!
  end   
end
```

I generated the following migrations for it:

```
class CreatePaypalPayments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :paypal_payments do |t|
      t.integer :order_id
      t.integer :payment_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class AddDetailsToPaypalPayment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :paypal_payments, :state, :string
    add_column :paypal_payments, :amount, :decimal
    add_column :paypal_payments, :cc, :string
    add_column :paypal_payments, :cm, :string
  end
end
```

After the migration the table looks something like:

```
development_database=# select * from paypal_payments;
 id | order_id | payment_id | created_at | updated_at | state | amount | cc | cm
```

But when I try to initialize an object of this model, I'm getting the `unknown attribute: payment_id`.

```
@paypal_payment = PaypalPayment.new(:payment_id => params[:tx], :state => params[:st], :cc => params[:cc], :cm => params[:cm], :order_id => params[:id])
```

**EDIT:** db/schema.rb:

```
create_table "paypal_payments", :force => true do |t| 
    t.integer "order_id" 
    t.integer "payment_id" 
    t.datetime "created_at" 
    t.datetime "updated_at" 
    t.string "state" 
    t.decimal "amount" 
    t.string "cc" 
    t.string "cm" 
end
```

Comment: Although the database has the correct column, it would be worth checking that Rails knows about the column. This could be to do with how the initial table was created.

What does the Rails schema table look like?

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale: The schema looks like `  create_table "paypal_payments", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "payment_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "state"
    t.decimal  "amount"
    t.string   "cc"
    t.string   "cm"
  end
`

Comment: sorry, can't think of anything else. Might be worth posting the full error output though?

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale : has it got something to do with the base class of the model??

Comment: What happens when you type this in the rails console:
@p = PaypalPament.new
@p.payment_id = 1

Comment: btw when you perform migrations, you should use `after: :attr_name` if you'd like to position the column in mysql :)

Comment: @TheJKFever : I tried that, But i'm getting `undefined method `payment_id``

Comment: Yea it sounds like the column or name is not there. You should maybe do a new migration to add it, or do what Rich Peck suggests, and add an attr_accessor. I recommend the first one. It's possible the payment_id is coming from the PaymentMethod class when you output development_database=# select * from paypal_payments;
That seems to be throwing us all off.

Comment: @TheJKFever : I have already done the migration to add `order_id` and `payment_id` at the time of creating the `PaypalPayment` model. The `PaymentMethod` does not contain `payment_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to model inheritance in a relational database, Martin Fowler lists the following options:

1. [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) : all classes are stored in a single table
2. [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)  : all classes have their own table
3. [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) : only concrete classes have a table (e.g. in your example `PaymentMethod` if being abstract, would not have a table)

Now ActiveRecord [only supports STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Single+table+inheritance): single table inheritance.

So if you write

```
class PaypalPayment < PaymentMethod
```

ActiveRecord will assume STI and look for a type column, and furthermore, will only look for `payment_methods` table.

Depending on what you want, in most cases, STI is just perfect. Sometimes I prefer the Class and Concrete Table Inheritance better, but especially for associations this needs a little more householding, since:

- e.g. you have different payment-methods, but they are stored in different tables
- do you want to access all payment methods at once, you need the "abstract class"
- you need an association per possible payment-method
- if you have the "abstract class", how do you link to the "real payment method". One way is to include table-name and id of the child as the link.

There are lots of way to solve this, but always harder than using a single table. Also this is stretching the relational datamodel, as depending on the chosen solution, foreign key constraints are not automatically supported. I could go into detail,
but I am not sure if this is relevant, as your example seems a classic case for STI.

If you do want to use Class Table Inheritance or Concrete Table Inheritance, each class has to derive from `ActiveRecord::Base`` and you should include a module (or concern) with the shared behaviour if needed (since ruby does not support multiple inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to add the column "type" to your PaymentMethods table. This will allow it to be inheritable. Without the type column, when you instantiate a PaypalPayment, it thinks it's a PaymentMethod and hence has none of the unique fields of PaypalPayment. However when you add the column "type" to PaymentMethod, then it will store "PaypalPayment" and ActiveRecord knows to make the PaypalPayment methods available. You should probably make a model for PaymentMethod also and make sure it inherits ActiveRecord::Base

```
def change
  add_column :payment_methods, :type, :string
end
```

Here's some info:
http://www.archonsystems.com/devblog/2011/12/20/rails-single-table-inheritance-with-polymorphic-association/

Comment: `id` and `payment_id` are two separate columns in the table. So, do you mean paypal_payments_payment_id??

Comment: No you should be able to just use paypal_payments_id and that is what is being associated as id.
So every table has an id with it, and if you want to access that id explicitly you put the table name in front of it. Now you can add other ids to the table also, such as is done here with payment_id. (most likely for an association)

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you're trying to do here now... Reading over this now, It looks like that actually should work. Can you show what you're db/schema file shows for the paypal_payments table?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

Check your Rails Console --

```
$ rails c
$ payment = PaypalPayment.find(1)
$ payment.column_names #-> should reveal which columns Rails comes back with
```

Check Rails is picking up the attribute

For testing's sake, just try `attr_accessor :payment_id` to see if that works. You might not have permitted the attribute in your model

In Rails4, that means using `strong params`, but in Rails 3, I think it means using `attr_accessible` like this:

```
#app/models/paypal_payment.rb
Class PaypalPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :payment_id #-> tests parameter passing
    attr_accessor :payment_id #-> tests virtual attribute assignment
end
```

Comment: Oh sorry (my bad!). You should be getting `column_names` back from your `PaypalPayment` model... Are you sure the inheritance works correctly?

Comment: Getting the following column_names - `["id",
 "type",
 "name",
 "description",
 "active",
 "environment",
 "created_at",
 "updated_at",
 "deleted_at",
 "display_on"]`. is it because `PaymentMethod` does not have the remaining columns?? if so how can I access these attributes?

Comment: Ah I get it now. So you're only getting your "master" columns. How are you defining the relationship? This is something I am looking to work on

Comment: I have defined the follwing relationship in the model class: `class PaypalPayment < PaymentMethod
  belongs_to :order`

Comment: Sorry I meant in the PaymentMethod model?

Comment: I have not defined this class. There is just a table corresponding to this. it has same columns - `["id",  "type",  "name",  "description",  "active",  "environment",  "created_at",  "updated_at",  "deleted_at",  "display_on"]`

Comment: Hmmmm I will research this and get back to you if this is okay?

Comment: Sure. I'll also do the same

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late the show here, but if anyone is encountering a similar problem with Rails 5.1, in my case I was able to resolve the issue by including the following line in my parent classes

`self.abstract_class = true`